# How can I avoid my circles being on top of each other (CSS)?

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, geometry

I am trying to make a board of a game but at the moment of modifying the screen the circles are on the other side, I would like to know how to avoid it without having to reduce the size of the circles

**Use vuejs to make the loop** 
But once again you could do so

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="circle-container">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        .
        .
        .
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried to set maximums and minimums but I can not get it to work.

[I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFoUD.png)

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwfqR.png)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="circle-container">
        <div class="circle" v-for="i in 30"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS code

```
.wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 30px auto;
    }

    .circle-container {
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

    }

    .circle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

.circle:nth-child(1) {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(30vw);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(30vw);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(30vw);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(30vw);
        transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(30vw);
        background: #ff504f;
    }

    .circle:nth-child(2) {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg) translateX(30vw);
        -moz-transform: rotate(12deg) translateX(30vw);
        -ms-transform: rotate(12deg) translateX(30vw);
        -o-transform: rotate(12deg) translateX(30vw);
        transform: rotate(12deg) translateX(30vw);
        background: yellowgreen;
    }

    .circle:nth-child(3) {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg) translateX(30vw);
        -moz-transform: rotate(24deg) translateX(30vw);
        -ms-transform: rotate(24deg) translateX(30vw);
        -o-transform: rotate(24deg) translateX(30vw);
        transform: rotate(24deg) translateX(30vw);
        background: yellowgreen;
    }
```

.
.
.
. 
30 times

Comment: please add **working** code

Comment: The code is there

Comment: I know... BUT 1. `v-for="i in 30"` not work (or add tag with what library you use) 2. I can see any css to position circles in circle and backround

Comment: Ups Sorry... Done!

Comment: If you do not want them to overlap, then you cannot position them absolutely with responsive values.  Why not just give the container a fixed width?

Comment: @Pete I entered a fixed value and nothing changed

Comment: @tobifasc If I do it with 6 I would not get 30 circles(?)

Comment: Ah yeah it's because you are translating by a vw amount - needs to be fixed - anything over half the size of the container width will see them be not overlapping

Comment: @Pete Oh, thank you, now the problem is that by reducing the screen, the object goes out the screen

Comment: Yep you cannot have both non overlapping and responsive if you are not willing to reduce the size of the circles - if you are going to make it responsive, then every element of it must be responsive otherwise you get the issues you are experiencing, you cannot be selective of what to shrink and what not to